# Reloading python module with flattened namespace

Tags: python

I have a package with a similar structure as scipy/numpy, where you have a few main submodules, and each submodule contains functions from various files that have been flattened into the same namespace. Let's say

```
package/
  sub1/
    __init__.py
    file1.py
    file2.py
```

And then `sub1/__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from .file1 import func1, func2
from .file2 import func3
```

The result is that I can do

```
import package.sub1
package.sub1.func1()
```

**However**, the problem is that the following does not work:

```
>>> import package.sub1
-- change things in file1.py --
>>> reload(package.sub1)
```

The function does not update. It works if I do `import package.sub1.file1` instead, so there is something with flattening the namespace, that makes it lose the connection to the module. My main question is how I can still use the `reload` command, while still getting the benefits of being able to write sibling functions in separate files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `__init__.py` reload the files it imports when it is imported:

```
import file1
import file2
reload(file1)
reload(file2)

func1, func2 = file1.func1, file1.func2
func3 = file2.func3
```

That said, relying on `reload()` is generally a bad idea if you can avoid it.

Comment: That's a viable solution, thanks! I only want `reload()` to work during interactive iPython sessions during development, so the package in the end won't rely on it.